# running maven install on open projects only in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a multi-module application with many sub-modules.
I want to be able to run `maven install` on the open projects **ONLY** at one shot.

Running maven install on the parent pom will install ALL modules (most of the projects are closed or not even imported).

How to achieve this (preferably without having to create an eclipse plugin for this)?

Comment: Maven does not know which Eclipse project is open or not... I don't think you can do that without an Eclipse plugin, extending M2E.

Comment: run the mvn command with -pl <projectname>, which builds only the specified project.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think that the more relevant solution is specifying the command you want to execute in a script (.sh, .bat) and execute it from External Tool of Eclipse.

A more intrusive solution would be to add in the aggregator pom, one or several Maven profiles where you define the relevant modules for the build.

If several developers of your team have the same problematic as you, integrating it in the aggregator pom may be a very suitable solution otherwise if the need is not shared, scripts + External tools seems the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have need to create childs POM.xml for each module so that it depends on you You want used child POM.xml or not.

Hope this solved your issue.

Comment: each child is a maven project, so they all have pom.xml, but I don't want to do this one by one